# Several COUNTS on single SQL Query: Looking for efficiency

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum, multiple-conditions

I would just like  your oppinion on the efficiency of a query. I am counting values through a very large table (several million records).  This is MSSQL but I think it should apply to any database engine. What I am doing now is the following:

```
SELECT Task,
    COUNT(*) as Total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Active,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Active' AND AppType = 'MOBILE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ActiveMobile,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Active' AND AppType = 'WEB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ActiveWeb,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'OnHold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS onHold,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'onHold' AND AppType = 'MOBILE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS onHoldMobile,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'onHold' AND AppType = 'WEB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS onHoldWeb,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Active' OR Status = 'onHold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ActiveAndOnHold,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (Status = 'Active' OR Status = 'onHold') AND AppType = 'MOBILE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ActiveAndOnHoldMobile,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (Status = 'Active' OR Status = 'onHold') AND AppType = 'WEB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ActiveAndOnHoldWeb
FROM events
GROUP BY Task;
```

I realize I am counting the same thing over again and I should be able to add partial results but, to be honest, I could not figure out how to do it without traversing the table more than once.

The actual query has about 20 more SUMs with combinations of the same data.  The query takes a while to run (about two hours).  I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Any suggestion is very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Aside from query optimization you could see if your SQL Server instance has some resources left and play with its maximum degree of parallelism (a.k.a. [maxdop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-server-configuration-option)). If it is different from 0, then you could add `option (maxdop x)` after your query with `x` being the maximum number of threads for each operator in your query plan (`0` = unlimited). Keep an eye on the CPU en I/O load if you are going to run this anywhere near production!

Comment: 2 hours!!!  How large is the data?  In this case, I would expect the cost to mostly be the data movement for the `group by`, not the number of `sum()`s.

Comment: Thanks @Sander, I will check that out.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff. I wish I knew why it takes that long.

Comment: `CASE WHEN Status = 'Active' AND Status = 'onHold'`, if not a typo, it will always be false:0 ,,, you could add sum(active)+sum(onhold) calculated already in the query (Active, onHold) to get the sum of active&onhold.. the same goes for active(mobile)+onhold(mobile) etc....

Comment: Hi @Iptr, yes sorry it was typo, I meant OR.  I fixed it in the question. And how is the syntaxys fr the SUM, I was trying just as you said but I get a syntax error.  Thanks!

Comment: instead of `SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Active' OR Status = 'onHold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ActiveAndOnHold,` use : `SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /*Active*/ + SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'OnHold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /*onHold*/   as ActiveAndOnHold` .... the same for mobile etc...just add the corresponding sums() instead of creating new case expressions with Active OR onHold etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep intermediate flags.  I doubt this will speed your query, but it will make it simpler to maintain:

```
SELECT Task, COUNT(*) as Total,
        SUM(is_active) AS Active,
        SUM(is_active * is_mobile) AS ActiveMobile,
        . . .
FROM events e CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN Status = 'Active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
             (CASE WHEN Status = 'OnHold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
             (CASE WHEN AppType = 'WEB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
             (CASE WHEN AppType = 'MOBILE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
             . . .
     ) v(is_active, is_onhold, is_web, is_mobile)
GROUP BY Task;
```

This might affect performance if your comparisons are actually more cumbersome than simple string equality.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff, you are right that is cleaner.   Thanks for the idea. I will test it out.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your query has a fully covering index.  This can make a huge difference.  Make sure your query plan is using multiple cores.  If you look at the query plan, look for a gather operator.  This is related to the maxdop suggestion above.  Consider using a detail detail subquery that takes the row count.  Then another query that breaks your fields out into the final results.

```
select F1, sum(case when A = 1 then ItemCount else 0 end) SummaryField
from 
(
  select F1, A, count(*) ItemCount
  from T1
  group by F1, A
) T2
group by F1
```

If all else fails, consider caching the aggregate results in a table that just contains the result set from your aggregate query.  The original aggregate query can be run every two hours.  But querying the cache table will contain fewer records and will be much easier to query.